# Unable to load Environment Variable Path with Jboss and PHP

Tags: php, jboss, windows-10, cgi, fastcgi

I am trying to use the Oracle connectivity by oci_connect function with JBoss (where Server API is CGI/FastCGI), I am unable to show environment variable over phpinfo() function with JBoss(where Server API is CGI/FastCGI), which is already working fine with PHP and Apache.
Below are the parameters which are showing by jboss/(CGI/FastCGI), system environment variable `PATH`(which is needed to enable the oci8 module of php) and some other parameters are missing with JBoss.

```
CGI/FastCGI Environment
Variable    Value
PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN   5
PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS   10000
REDIRECT_STATUS 200
SystemRoot  C:\WINDOWS
__COMPAT_LAYER  ElevateCreateProcess

Apache Environment
HTTP_COOKIE csrftoken=5LL6M3KDqW6zbW947SUd5qKiDNYvkDiKtNTKO8kbAhiECWitdjdncL2ZRnQQyYVl; PHPSESSID=s2fcp7cbjijjc77i5g195koiil
PATH    C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\RSA SecurID Token Common........;
```

Can anyone provide the help/steps to display the environment variable with JBoss and CGI/FastCGI?
FYI: I am using the window 10 environment.

Answer (score 0):

As I verified the my Project.war file, which has been bundled the php-cgi.exe with php 5.6, here we had the wrong version of **java.inc** file which Compile The PHP/Java Bridge for PHP library. 
I changed my java.inc file then the issue have resolved, and now I can see the oci_connect module inside the phpinfo()
So I realized that, I would have need to use correct [java](https://github.com/tholu/phpjavabridge/blob/master/Java.inc.php) bridge file.

[OCI8 Module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g42Rk.png)